# How to create array of TabControl (pre-designed on Form) using VC++?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, visual-c++, c++-cli

I want to create **Array of TabControl** object. Here TabControl (named 'tabControlCalibration' and **pre-designed on GUI form**).

All I want to do is to create Array of this predefined and pre-designed TabControl on the form.

My purpose is to create and show **TabControl (already designed)** dynamically to the user.

I am using programming language as **C++/CLI**.

For the solution, should I need to use Custom-Controls or User-Controls? If yes, then how to implement the same. I am new to C++/CLI .

Comment: You want to create an array with only one element in it?  You are not programming in VC++ or C++, the language is called C++/CLI

Comment: Thank you so much for reply! Actually, I wanted to know if it is possible to use Custom Controls or equivalent concept for the solution here ?